# How to create a data click DIV content change fade up effect through jquery?

Tags: jquery

I wish to change the content when li is click but the content is fading but not changing. May I know is it my coding structure wrong?

```
$(".slide-button li a").on('click', function() {
    var page = $('.slide-button li a').attr('data-page');
    $(".slide-container .slide:not('.hide')").stop().fadeOut('fast', function() {
        $(this).fadeIn('slow').removeClass('hide');
        $('.slide-container .slide[data-page="' + page + '"]').addClass('hide');
    });
);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/08x9wgmr/4/

Comment: Thank you for helping me to correct the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First for get `data-page` value of each anchor need to use `$(this)` then you can hide all `.slide` then `fadeIn()` the target like below. Also instead of using a `class` to hide, you can use `hide()` function.

```js
$(".slide-button li a").on('click', function() {
  var page = $(this).attr('data-page');
  //--------------^ Use $(this)
  console.log(page);
  $(".slide-container .slide").hide();
  $(".slide-container .slide[data-page='" + page + "']").fadeIn(600);
});
```

```css
.slide-container .slide.hide {
  display: none;
}

.slide {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slide-container">
  <div class="slide quote-1" data-page="slide-1">
    <div class="inner-content">
      <h5>Slide 1</h5>
      <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide quote-2 hide" data-page="slide-2">
    <div class="inner-content">
      <h5>Slide 2</h5>
      <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide quote-3 hide" data-page="slide-3">
    <div class="inner-content">
      <h5>Slide 3</h5>
      <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<ul class="slide-button">
  <li><a href="#/" data-page="slide-1">slide 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#/" data-page="slide-2">slide 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#/" data-page="slide-3">slide 3</a></li>
</ul>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Keep going :) Also Accept/Up vote this answer if solved your problem @user9030616